# R : specific processing

Tags: r, dataframe, trading

I need to process a batch of data frames fetched from a MySQL database.
My data frames are trading candlesticks (1 minute).
I have the whole bunch of candlesticks loaded ('data') and I need to process them by batch of 60 (duration), 360, 720 and 1440 (up to 1 day).
I created this function "createKLine" which takes into account the duration of my final candlestick, the index at which to start processing my bunch of candlesticks, and the data.

```
createKLine <- function(duration, index, data) {
  maxIndex = min(index+duration-1, dim(data)[1])
  open = data$open[index]
  close = data$close[maxIndex]
  low=min(data$low[index:maxIndex])
  high=max(data$high[index:maxIndex])
  open_time=min(data$open_time[index:maxIndex])
  close_time=max(data$close_time[index:maxIndex])
  return(
    data.frame(
      open=open, 
      close=close, 
      high=high, 
      low=low, 
      open_time=open_time, 
      close_time=close_time, 
      interval_id=paste(duration,'m', sep='')
    )
  )
}
```

Would you know any other more efficient way of doing this and get new data frames taking into account the [i:i+duration], and maybe even to process the whole bunch of data at once ?

UPDATE: As requested, here is a subset of 'data':

```
structure(list(open = c(0.000195, 0.000195, 0.000195, 0.000195, 
0.000195, 0.000195, 0.000195, 0.000195, 0.000195, 0.000195, 0.000195, 
0.00169996, 0.0016989, 0.00049999, 0.00048, 0.00038, 0.00030999, 
0.00028501, 0.00028088, 0.00028087), close = c(0.000195, 0.000195, 
0.000195, 0.000195, 0.000195, 0.000195, 0.000195, 0.000195, 0.000195, 
0.000195, 0.000195, 0.00169996, 0.00169996, 0.00049999, 0.00042, 
0.00029001, 0.00031, 0.0002809, 0.000275, 0.0002809), high = c(0.000195, 
0.000195, 0.000195, 0.000195, 0.000195, 0.000195, 0.000195, 0.000195, 
0.000195, 0.000195, 0.000195, 0.00169996, 0.00169996, 0.00049999, 
0.00048, 0.00038, 0.00031, 3e-04, 0.00028088, 0.0002809), low = c(0.000195, 
0.000195, 0.000195, 0.000195, 0.000195, 0.000195, 0.000195, 0.000195, 
0.000195, 0.000195, 0.000195, 0.00169996, 0.0016989, 0.00049999, 
0.00042, 0.00029001, 0.00028091, 0.0002809, 0.000275, 0.00028087
), open_time = c(1.512045e+12, 1512045060000, 1512045120000, 
1512045180000, 1512045240000, 1512045300000, 1512045360000, 1512045420000, 
1512045480000, 1512045540000, 1512045600000, 1512045660000, 1512045720000, 
1512045780000, 1512045840000, 1512045900000, 1512045960000, 1512046020000, 
1512046080000, 1512046140000), close_time = c(1512045059999, 
1512045119999, 1512045179999, 1512045239999, 1512045299999, 1512045359999, 
1512045419999, 1512045479999, 1512045539999, 1512045599999, 1512045659999, 
1512045719999, 1512045779999, 1512045839999, 1512045899999, 1512045959999, 
1512046019999, 1512046079999, 1512046139999, 1512046199999)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

And here is how I call 'createKLine':

```
computeKLines <- function(data, cols, duration) {
  index = 1
  max = dim(data)[1]
  newklines <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = 7, nrow = 0)), cols)
  while(index <= max) {
    newklines <- rbind(newklines, createKLine(duration = duration, index = index, data = data))
    index = index + duration
  }
  return(newklines)
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help !

UPDATE 2:
Got it. Thanks to @Frank. First, I installed the 'data.table' package.
Then :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, .(low = min(low), high = max(high), open = first(open), close = last(close), open_time = first(open_time), close_time = last(close_time)), by=.(int_id = rep(1:nrow(data), length.out=nrow(data), each=60))]
```

I have another question though. What if my rows are not all present ? i.e. sometimes, I need to select only 50 rows (max 60), depending on open_time and close_time (close_time - open_time has to be < 60 * 60 * 1000 ==> 60 minutes in milliseconds).

Comment: Please include a little bit of sample data - `dput` is great for making a copy/pastable version of an R object and sharing it. We don't need a ton of data, just 10-20 rows that illustrate what's going on and we can run your function on.

Comment: When you say *"I have the whole bunch of candlesticks loaded ('data') and I need to process them by batch of 60 (duration), ..."* do you mean that all your data frames are combined into a single data frame named `data`? Or maybe you've loaded them into a `list` of data frames named `data`? Or something else...?

Comment: Yes @Gregor. It is just one data frame containing all records, which I need to process by batch of 60, 360, ...

Comment: You are computing summaries by group. Probably a package like dplyr or data.table would be a good fit. Both have good tutorials or you could just try editing `library(data.table); setDT(dat)[, .(m = min(open), mm = max(open)), by=.(int_id = rep(1:nrow(dat), length.out=nrow(dat), each=60))]` into what you want.